# Disk Brake or V Brake

Tags: brakes

I am willing to buy a new mtb.But i am totally confused about which brake to choose.I want to do daily communication by my mtb. and also often want to do stunts.in this circumstances which kind of brake is best for me???

Answer (score 0):

Disk brakes hands down. V-brakes are difficult to adjust, can get misaligned and destroy tire and rim (happens to me, very quickly). Disk brakes allows you to change your wheels easily and works even when wet and muddy. With v-brakes you always have the problem of different pad-to-rim separation for left and right pads due to differences in springs tension. Disk brakes works even if your wheel is wobbly.

For me, disk brakes (and overall weight) were the main reason for switching from supermarket steel MTB to a real aluminum MTB costing 4x more.

Comment: Discs can be a disadvantage when doing stunts. If you're doing pedal grinds or riding skinnies you're eventually going to bang your rotors on something which pretty much ruins them in one shot.